# how to group and Separate object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to group and Separate object of an array that comes from the server. array like this:
(MOVINGSTATE `s` This means that Stop and`m` moving. XPOINT and YPOINT This means that latitude and longitude of car.)

```
[{MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT:53.9172866,YPOINT: 26.518275},
{MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT: 53.9172866,YPOINT: 26.518275},
{MOVINGSTATE: "m",XPOINT: 54.0215383,YPOINT: 26.5275599},
{MOVINGSTATE: "m",XPOINT: 54.0102666,YPOINT: 26.4989583},
{MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT: 54.0016599,YPOINT: 26.5478316},..]
```

I want to if some `MOVINGSTATE` Continuous `s` goto new array and when `MOVINGSTATE` change to `m`goto new array and again `MOVINGSTATE`change to `s`  **goto new array**. all this new array object of another main array.
i use [loadash](https://lodash.com/)

```
var aaa = _loadash.groupBy(props,'MOVINGSTATE')
```

but Output this :

```
{m:Array(2),s:Array(3)}
```

i want outpust like this:

```
[
 [
  {MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT:53.9172866,YPOINT: 26.518275},
  {MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT: 53.9172866,YPOINT: 26.518275}
  ],
 [
  {MOVINGSTATE: "m",XPOINT: 54.0215383,YPOINT: 26.5275599},
  {MOVINGSTATE: "m",XPOINT: 54.0102666,YPOINT: 26.4989583}
 ],
 [
  {MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT: 54.0016599,YPOINT: 26.5478316}
 ]
]
```

how to this thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let arr = 
[{MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT:53.9172866,YPOINT: 26.518275},
{MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT: 53.9172866,YPOINT: 26.518275},
{MOVINGSTATE: "m",XPOINT: 54.0215383,YPOINT: 26.5275599},
{MOVINGSTATE: "m",XPOINT: 54.0102666,YPOINT: 26.4989583},
{MOVINGSTATE: "s",XPOINT: 54.0016599,YPOINT: 26.5478316}];

  let result =  arr.reduce( (accumulator, cur) => {
    const key = cur["MOVINGSTATE"];
    const keyExists = accumulator.find(obj => obj.key === key);
    if (!keyExists) {
      accumulator.push({key,value:[cur]});
      return accumulator;      
    } else if(accumulator[accumulator.length -1] && accumulator[accumulator.length -1].key === key){
        accumulator[accumulator.length -1].value.push(cur);
        return accumulator;
    } else {
      accumulator.push({key,value:[cur]});
      return accumulator; 
    }
        
  }, [])
  .map(obj => obj.value)
```